# How can i animate the new posts coming from a snapshot in react.js

Tags: reactjs, animation, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to make a simple fade animation when a new post is rendered
im using Firebase Firestore like this:(Feed.js)

```
function Feed() {
const {currentUser} = useAuth()
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    db.firestore().collection('posts').orderBy("timestamp", "desc").onSnapshot(snapshot => (
        setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({id: doc.id, data: doc.data()
        })))
    ))
    }, []);
return <div className="feed">
    { posts.map((post,key ) => (
        <Post
            postwebid={key}
            key={post.data.id}
            profilePic={post.data.profilePic}
            message={post.data.message}
            username={post.data.username}
            timestamp={post.data.timestamptext}
            image={post.data.image}
            id={post.id}
            ownerID={post.data.owner}
        />

    ))}
</div>
 }

 export default Feed;
```

so, every time i make a new post it renders correctly as i want

the problem:
when i add an animation with spring it only displays when the app loads for the first time (fading in all the posts on screen at same time), but not when a new post comes over the screen (a single post).

im animating the posts like this: (Post.js)

```
  function Post({profilePic,image,username,timestamp,message,id,ownerID}) {
  const props = useSpring({opacity: 1, from: {opacity: 0}})

  return <animated.div className="post" style={props}>
    <div className="post__top">
        <Avatar src={profilePic}
                className="post__avatar"/>
        <div className="post__topInfo">
            <h3>{username}</h3>
            <p>{timestamp}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="post__topActions">
            <PostMenu id={id} ownerID={ownerID}/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="post__bottom">
        <p>{message}</p>
    </div>

    <div className="post__image">
        <img src={image} alt=""/>
    </div>

    <div className="post__options">
        <div className="post__option"> <HeartIcon/></div>
        <div className="post__option"><PurchaseIcon/></div>
    </div>
</animated.div>
}

 export default Post;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Framer-motion or Flip move.
post.js:

```
const Post = forwardRef(({name,description,message,photoUrl},ref) =>{
return (
    <div ref={ref} className="post">
        <div className="post_header">
            <Avatar src={photoUrl}>{name[0]}</Avatar>
            <div className="post_info">
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <p>{description}</p> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="post_body">
                <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="post_button">
            <InputOption Icon={ThumbUpOffAltIcon} title="like" color="gray"/>
            <InputOption Icon={CommentOutlinedIcon} title="Comment" color="gray"/>
            <InputOption Icon={ShareOutlinedIcon} title="Share" color="gray"/>
            <InputOption Icon={SendOutlinedIcon} title="Send" color="gray"/>
        </div>
    </div>

);
```

})

feed.js

```
<FlipMove>
        {posts.map( ({id,data:{name,description,message,photoUrl}}) => (
            <Post 
                key={id}
                name={name}
                description={description}
                message={message}
                photoUrl={photoUrl}
                />
        ))}
        </FlipMove>
```